# Trying to mount ddrescue .img file Failed to load $MFT

Tags: mount, data-recovery, ddrescue

Here is what ive done to try and mount.

```
root@PartedMagic:/media/sdb2# parted recovery.img
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /media/sdb2/recovery.img
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) unit                                                             
Unit?  [compact]? B                                                       
(parted) print                                                            
Model:  (file)
Disk /media/sdb2/recovery.img: 10306975498240B
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start       End            Size           Type     File system  Flags
 1      1048576B    105906175B     104857600B     primary  ntfs
 2      105906176B  500105740287B  499999834112B  primary  ntfs         boot

(parted) exit                                                             
  align-check TYPE N                       check partition N for TYPE(min|opt)
        alignment
  help [COMMAND]                           print general help, or help on
        COMMAND


root@PartedMagic:/media/sdb2# mount -t ntfs -o loop,ro,offset=105906176 recovery.img mountpoint
The MFT is not self-contained: No such file or directory
Failed to load $MFT: No such file or directory
Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': No such file or directory
root@PartedMagic:/media/sdb2#
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but I don't think `mount loop` option is to be used like that. I suggest you try to let linux handle the partition table. as root:

```
losetup --find --show recovery.img
```

This returns, for example, `/dev/loop0`. Then you might need to run, as root, `partprobe` so that you now have also `/dev/loop0p1` and `/dev/loop0p2`, the two partitions in your drive image.

You can now mount each with your `mount` command. without `loop` and `offset`:

```
mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/loop0p1 mountpoint1
mount -t ntfs -o ro /dev/loop0p2 mountpoint2
```

Comment: You also use `-P`/`--partscan` with `losetup` to avoid the need to run `partprobe`.